# Como ejecuto un proyecto de django al arrancar el ordenador

Tags: django, django-admin

Estoy intentando hacer que cuando arranque mi servidor de ubuntu se ejecute un proyecto que he creado en django para no tener que hacer el runserver cada vez que quiera tener acceso al proyecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplemente crea con systemd (si es que lo tiene en su distro (ubuntu si lo tiene)

> edite como superusuario (root o con sudo) /etc/systemd/system/servicename.service (cambie servicename por el nombre que elija)

```
[Unit]
Description=Ejemplo
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=lorenzo
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python /home/lorenzo/temporal/sample/sample.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Cambie el apartado descripición por la descripcion de la tarea que quiere ejecutar al inicio del sistema, cambia el apartado User por el nombre de su usuario, (si quiere ejecutar como root el proyecto, escriba root ahi), el apartado ExecStart es el comando que se ejecutara cuando se inicie su servicio, en este caso se abriria con python 2 el archivo /home/lorenzo/temporal/sample/sample.py pero este archivo no va a existir

Ahora guarde el archivo, y ejecute:

Si tiene sudo:

```
sudo systemctl enable servicename
```

depende del nombre que incluyese el servicio

ahora se ejecutara cuando arranque el equipo, el servicio se activara la proxima vez que inicie su pc, si quiere activarlo ahora ejecute:

```
sudo systemctl start servicename
```

Comment: Gracias canal PC, tengo una pregunta en el apartado ExecStart, la primera ruta es la que tengo que poner o tengo que sustituirla.

Comment: el parametro ExecStart es lo que systemd va a ejecutar cuando se inicie el servicio, si  lo ejecuta con el comando python3, puede colocar el comando /usr/bin/python3 file-dir (file-dir lo reemplaza por la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo)